# Vertical ViewPager likeTikTok app showing error in android studio

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am building TikTok like a small application in which I am trying to create a vertical viewpager scroller in which I am getting an error when I am adding a fragment to the list. I have googled it a lot but unable to find the answer

HomeFragment.java

```
package com.example.musically.ui.home;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;


import com.example.musically.PageFragment1;
import com.example.musically.PageFragment2;
import com.example.musically.R;
import com.example.musically.VPagerAdapter;
import com.example.musically.VerticalViewPager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    private VerticalViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View viewInflate=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        List<Fragment> list;
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new PageFragment1());
        list.add(new PageFragment2());
//        viewPager=getView().findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
//        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        return viewInflate;
    }


}
```

pageFragment1.java

```
package com.example.musically;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link PageFragment1#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class PageFragment1 extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public PageFragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment PageFragment1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PageFragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PageFragment1 fragment = new PageFragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false);
    }
}
```

pageFragment2.java

```
package com.example.musically;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link PageFragment2#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class PageFragment2 extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public PageFragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment PageFragment2.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PageFragment2 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PageFragment2 fragment = new PageFragment2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page2, container, false);
    }
}
```

VerticalViewPager.java

```
package com.example.musically;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public VerticalViewPager(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    private void init()
    {
    setPageTransformer(true,new VerticalPage());
    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }
    private MotionEvent getIntercambioXY(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        float width=getWidth();
        float height=getHeight();
        float newX=(ev.getY()/height)*width;
        float newY=(ev.getX()/width)*height;
        ev.setLocation(newX,newY);
        return ev;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean intercept=super.onInterceptTouchEvent(getIntercambioXY(ev));
        getIntercambioXY(ev);
        return intercept;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(getIntercambioXY(ev));
    }

    private class VerticalPage implements ViewPager.PageTransformer{


        @Override
        public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
            if(position<-1)
            {
                page.setAlpha(0);
            }else if(position<=1){
                page.setAlpha(1);
                page.setTranslationX(page.getWidth()*-position);
                float yPosition=position*page.getHeight();
                page.setTranslationY(yPosition);
            }else{
                page.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.musically;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment;

public class VPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragmentList;

    public VPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragmentList)
    {
    super(fm);
    this.fragmentList=fragmentList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

fragment_page1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PageFragment1">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_page2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PageFragment2">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello_blank_fragment2" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Error log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.musically, PID: 31918
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.viewpager.VerticalViewPager
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.viewpager.VerticalViewPager
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.viewpager.VerticalViewPager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.musically-lmyD6ZMuBOXRyK1vN2MX8w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.musically-lmyD6ZMuBOXRyK1vN2MX8w==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:612)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:775)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:925)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:886)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:521)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at com.example.musically.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:48)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1188)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7279)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:185)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:170)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:147)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2036)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7081)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
```

Comment: the problem seems due to the xml where you are including a "com.viewpager.VerticalViewPager", can you please add also this one in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered switching to the new **ViewPager2** to avoid all this extra code you have written?

ViewPager2 supports:

- Vertical Orientation
- RTL Direction

[Migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#vertical-support)

No need for custom ViewPager when using ViewPager2:

Vertical Orientation

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

RTL Support:

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl" />
```

With this new component you can use `RecyclerView.Adapter` or `FragmentStatePager` as an Adapter.

I used ViewPager2 with BottomNavigation and its a lot more functional and easier to work with.

A good tutorial can be found [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8192680-viewpager2-in-android-getting-started)